# Rearrange 2D numpy array into a column vector maintaining line indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have a numpy array of this form:

[image]

I would like to rearrange it so that columns will be stacked together maintaining their initial indexes (which probably will be new columns).

I would like to end up with something like this:

```
Jan2017 | 0 | 0
Feb2017 | 0 | 1
Mar2017 | 0 | 1
...
Jan2017 | 1 | 0 
Feb2017 | 1 | 0 etc
```

where the first and second columns represent the indexes of the initial array

Comment: Please provide a very simple example using an array like `np.arange(15).reshape((3, 5))`

Comment: That looks more like a Pandas data frame (or similar) than a NumPy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stack an indices array and the flattened and transposed values from your (probably) `DataFrame`.

For example:

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [0,1,1,0,0,1,0],
                   1: [0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
                   2: [1,0,1,0,1,0,0]},
                  index=['Jan2017', 'Feb2017', 'Mar2017', 'Apr2017', 'May2017', 'Jun2017', 'Jul2017'])
```

Could be processed like this:

```
>>> np.stack([np.repeat(np.arange(len(df.columns)), len(df)), df.values.T.ravel()], axis=1)
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

The [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) is used to create the indices:

```
>>> np.repeat(np.arange(len(df.columns)), len(df))
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

The [`.T`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) transposed the array, and [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html) flattens it:

```
>>> df.values.T.ravel()
array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

And then stacked "row-wise" (therefore the `axis=1`) using [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html)

Answer (score 0):

Say you matrix is saved in `A`, then you get the vector by `A.transpose().flatten()`

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

print(A)
print(A.transpose().flatten())
```